# php resize image based on weight on page php

Tags: php, image, resize

I need to resize image based on weight on my page php.

Ex: I have image of 10MB, when I upload image I want to resize to 5MB.

It's possible?

Comment: What does your research about that topic show?

Comment: You can't predict how big the file will be. Also 10 mpix image with small compression can be as big as 30 mpix with higher compression.

Comment: Your suggestions give me the ability to resize to a certain percentage, but so I do not know if the resulting file is still too big (or too small). It's possible resize to a fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$filename = 'http://www.yoursite.com/images/cowboybebop27.JPG';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$dest='temp_image.jpg';
imagejpeg($image, null, 10);
imagejpeg($image, $dest, 10);
?>
```

The above code will pull an image and save it at the file location of temp_image.jpg.

```
 imagejpeg($image, null, 10); //This line displays the image with a quality of 10% which is roughly 1/10 the original file size as well.

imagejpeg($image, $dest, 10); //This line saves the image with an image quality of 10%.
```

see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using a library, take a look at [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/).

```
<?php
include "path/to/WideImage.php";

$image = 'path/to/image.jpg';
$wi_image = WideImage::load($image);

//Get the file size & dimensions of the image
$size = filesize($image);
$dimensions = getfilesize($image);

//Determine image size
if ($size > 10000000) {
    //Image is over 10MB - half dimensions
    $resized = $wi_image->resize(
        $dimensions[0] / 2,  //half of width
        $dimensions[1] / 2   //half of height
    );

    //Save image
    $resized->saveToFile('small.jpg');
}
?>

<img src="small.jpg" />
```

It's worth noting that this will not necessarily halve image size but in most cases it will make the size smaller.